Book on Commutative algebra.
I just learned a little bit about commutative algebra from A term of Commutative Algebra by Allen B. ALTMAN and Steven L. KLEIMAN
it's great and I like the writing style. However the book doesn't have a section on kahler differential. I also tried looking it up on stack project, However it's more like a dictionary to look up than a book to study. Can anyone recommend me some books or documents that write about kahler differential ?, thanks a lot.
